Bypassing datetime ValueError Exception to have a datetime for date conversion
I need to convert a jalali calendar to a datetime column since in other tables I need to have a date column instead of string.
The string values in the column could be like below
from datetime import datetime
dt=datetime.strptime("1403-02-31","%Y-%m-%d")

but it gives below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bazargani.mehdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\_strptime.py", line 554, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bazargani.mehdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\_strptime.py", line 520, in _strptime
    julian = datetime_date(year, month, day).toordinal() - \
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: day is out of range for month

It is obvious since February doesn't have 31 days but I need to do above conversions.
Is there a way to bypass above error in python datetime?

Check out jdatetime library.

I have to use datetime not jdatetime due to compatibility issues in downstream applications.

You need to use jdatetime:
import jdatetime
from datetime import datetime

jalali_date_str = "1403-02-31"

try:
    jalali_date = jdatetime.date(*map(int, jalali_date_str.split('-')))
    gregorian_date = jalali_date.togregorian()
    dt = datetime(gregorian_date.year, gregorian_date.month, gregorian_date.day)
    print(dt)
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Error converting date: {e}")


which returns
2024-05-20 00:00:00

